# Taking an input and processing it

Tags: python-3.x

```
def modify(text):
    p = text.replace('a' , '@')
    q = p.replace('s' , '$')
    a = p.replace('i' , '!')
    print(a)

def encrypt(text):
    a = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    b = b'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
    atob = bytes.maketrans(a , b)
    print(text.translate(atob))

def decrypt(text):
    a = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    b = b'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
    btoa = bytes.maketrans(b , a)
    print(text.translate(btoa))

do_what = input()
#something to add here...
```

I want to know if there is a way to take the input from a use (what is to be done) and then the program does what is necessary. For example- If the input is encrypt('hello'), then the required output is produced.

I know that we can use conditional statements to do so but I wanted to know if there was a certain command using which it can be done.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval` function like this:

```
eval(input())
```

It takes a string as argument and evaluates it. You can read the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Here is an example:

```
>>> def f():
...   print("function call")
... 
>>> eval(input())
f()
function call
```

Answer (score 1):

The input data is stored in the do_what variable so just use that as the argument for which ever function you want.
`encrypt(str(do_what))`
or

```
do_what = str(input())
print(encrypt(do_what))
```

If I understand your question correctly but the easiest way is to have your functions return a text variable.

Comment: Actually, I want to know a (universal) way which can accept any of the arguments. Like if I run it in a loop and use a different argument each time, it halts with the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are almost done just type the following

```
    # encrypting
    encrypted=encrypt(do_what)
    print("encrypted data")
    # decrypting
    dec=decrypt(encrypted) 
    print(dec+"is the decrypted data")
    #modifying
    m=modify(do_what)
    print("modified data is"+m)
```

This should work if you have typed the function correctly.